# SQL Select Statement using dates in same column to add a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

This first select statement will display data based on a date. so will the second select statement.  Both of the dates are in one column i want to subtract the Daily Meter amounts from the two dates in one datagridview.

```
Select Machine.ID,Clientinfo.Clientname,Machine.MachineLocation, Machine.MachineType,DailyMeter,DailyCashAmt,DailyCardAmt,DailyCashAmt+DAilyCardAmt as TOTALAMT,Dailydate
from  Machine 
inner join Clientinfo on Clientinfo.ID = Machine.MachineID 
inner join DailyInput on Dailyinput.DailyId = Machine.ID 
 Where Clientinfo.ClientRoutenum = '1' and dailydate = '10-11-18'

(select DailyMeter from DailyInput where Dailydate = '10-10-18')
```

the result of these queries is two  results one of each select.  I want the lower result to be part of the first result so i can subtract the dailymeter amount of 10-11-18 from the daily meter amount of 10-10-18. i put them here this way just to be clear. top 1 doesn't help. can't put the select in the first as a sub because there is more than one row. ANy help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I assumed one machine have one record per day in DailyInput table

```
Select Machine.ID, Clientinfo.Clientname, Machine.MachineLocation, Machine.MachineType, DailyMeter, DailyCashAmt, 
       DailyCardAmt, DailyCashAmt+DAilyCardAmt as TOTALAMT, Dailydate, di2.DailyMeter as LastDayMeter
  from Machine inner join Clientinfo on Clientinfo.ID = Machine.MachineID 
               inner join DailyInput on Dailyinput.DailyId = Machine.ID 
               left outer join DailyInput as di2 on di2.DailyId = Machine.ID AND di2.Dailydate = '10-10-18'
 Where Clientinfo.ClientRoutenum = '1' 
   and dailydate = '10-11-18'
```

Comment: There are multiple records daily.  This will work fine i just had to alias all of the fields involved.  a simplified version with one table that gives me the results is this.

Comment: Select a.dailyID,a.Dailymeter c,a.Dailydate, b.DailyId, b.dailymeter p,b.dailydate,isnull(a.dailymeter,0)-isnull(b.dailymeter,0) as diff
  
 from Dailyinput a 
inner join dailyinput b on b.Dailyid = a.DailyId
 where b.dailydate = '10-11-18' and a.dailydate = '10-12-18'

Comment: Mr. B. Feld, I think, my code help you if so please mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to pivot the dates:

```
Select m.ID, ci.Clientname, m.MachineLocation, m.MachineType,
       max(case when di.dailydate = '10-11-18' then di.DailyMeter end) as dailymeter_date2,
       max(case when di.dailydate = '10-11-18' then di.DailyCashAmt end) as DailyCashAmt_date2,
       max(case when di.dailydate = '10-11-18' then di.DailyCardAmt end) as DailyCardAmt_date2,
       max(case when di.dailydate = '10-11-18' then di.DailyCashAmt + di.DAilyCardAmt end) as totalamt_date2,
       max(case when di.dailydate = '10-10-18' then di.DailyMeter end) as dailymeter_date1,
       max(case when di.dailydate = '10-10-18' then di.DailyCashAmt end) as DailyCashAmt_date1,
       max(case when di.dailydate = '10-10-18' then di.DailyCardAmt end) as DailyCardAmt_date1,
       max(case when di.dailydate = '10-10-18' then di.DailyCashAmt + di.DAilyCardAmt end) as totalamt_date1,
from  Machine m inner join
      Clientinfo ci
      on ci.ID = m.MachineID inner join
      DailyInput di
      on di.DailyId = m.ID 
where ci.ClientRoutenum = '1' and
      ci.dailydate in ('10-11-18', '10-10-18')
group by m.ID, ci.Clientname, m.MachineLocation, m.MachineType;
```

If `daildate` is being stored as a date, the comparison value should be in YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD format.